# InfluxDB placeholder "Empty bound parameter"

Tags: sql, node.js, get, influxdb

I'm struggling to format a InfluxDB query using placeholders.

Here I query with multiple placeholders.
The values are defined in the placeholders object, as seen below,

```
let query = `SELECT grid_ref_x, grid_ref_y, label FROM position
WHERE "label" = $<label> and time >= $<from> - $<interval>`;

const placeholders = {label: 'person', from: 'now()', interval: '5m'};
const resp = await influx.query(query, { placeholders });
```

Once sent, an `error 400 - error parsing query: empty bound parameter`

In the error I can see the GET request, where it appears that the Influx library has correctly formatted the placeholders under "params".

```
/query?p=root&u=root&db=heatmap&epoch=&q=SELECT grid_ref_x, grid_ref_y, label FROM position WHERE label = $<label> and time >= $<from> - $<interval>&rp=&params={"from":"now()","interval":"5h","label":"person"}
```

How do I correctly format my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing

```
let query = `SELECT grid_ref_x, grid_ref_y, label FROM position
WHERE "label" = $<label> and time >= $<from> - $<interval>`;
```

TO

```
let query = `SELECT grid_ref_x, grid_ref_y, label FROM position
WHERE "label" = $label and time >= $from - $interval`;
```

The difference is that you reference the Placeholders or bind parameters using **$variable_name** instead of **$<variable_name>**. Assuming you're using node_influx, you can remove the double quotes on your tags and it'll still work.

I used this PR as reference https://github.com/node-influx/node-influx/issues/587

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. The latest docs and sample for node_influx still show the $<variable_name> format